# CSS files and other resources missing from XAMPP to LAMPP

Tags: css, ubuntu, php-7, lampp

I just shifted my working environment form Windows to Ubuntu 16.04. I've been working with PHP. It worked well in xampp but shows missing file with LAMPP. My folder structure is:
Project
----indexfile
--css
----custom.css
This is how I included the css file:

```
<link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

What I noticed is missing the project folder name. But providing Project name before path won't be good idea. I even tried path like `./css/custom.css` but no luck.[image: Css missing files in ubuntu]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the absolute path?

Comment: @Syno — The `<link>` tag in the question uses an absolute path.

Comment: Whoops missed that, ignore my comment

Comment: Your folder structure doesn't make any sense. The number of `-`s suggest that you have a folder called `Project` containing a folder called `css` which contains a file called `customer.css` as well as a file called `indexcss` which is two levels down from `Project` with no parent folder.

Comment: and if you try without slash? "css/custom.css"

Comment: @JorgeBowen — They said they has tried `./css/custom.css` which is equivelent to `css/custom.css`

Comment: pff... the resources files are in the root folder of lampp? "/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.html" "/opt/lampp/htdocs/css/custom.css" ???

Comment: @JorgeBowen No. they're in var/www/html/myprojectfolder

Answer (score 0):

If you project folder is in /var/www/html you are not using lampp, you are using apache2, you must uninstall apache2 and reinstall lampp and put your project folder in /opt/lampp/htdocs, file permission to write here is needed,remember